# how to click on an input filed on a web page automatically as the page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making attendance system that require attendance to be taken by bar code reader. On a page I have an `input` box that requires the student id to be scanned by bar code reader. But as after one attendance the page reloads, I have to click the input field again and then scan by the bar code reader. Is there a way that as when the page loads, the input field is automatically clicked, so that I just scan the student id?

I have tried the following thing but it does not work:

```html
<body onload="myFunction()" >
    <form action="daily_attendance2_b.php" method="get">
        SID : <input type="number" id="box" name="roll_no"min=10000000 max=19999999 placeholder="Valid ID" >

        <input type="submit">
    </form>

    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            document.getElementById("box").click();
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the `focus()` method:

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("box").focus();
    }
</script>
```

Also note that placing this in a function is redundant as you've placed the code just before `</body>`, so you could remove the `onload` attribute and execute the line of code within the `script` block.

Answer (score 0):

If browser supports autofocus attribute (IE10+, FF4+, Chrome 5+), then you can make the input to be automatically focused on page load:

```
<input type="number" id="box" name="roll_no"min=10000000 max=19999999 placeholder="Valid ID" autofocus >
```

Otherwise you can use JS to focus it:

```
<script>
    if (document.addEventListener) document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', myFunction )
    else if (document.attachEvent) document.attachEvent( 'onreadystatechange', myFunction );

    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("box").focus();
    }
</script>
```